# What areas to avoid in Amsterdam for a family-friendly visit

Tags: amsterdam, family

I will be traveling to Amsterdam with elderly parents. They/we have a different "comfort zone" and would like to avoid walking through some liberal areas (such as the red light district or cannabis cafes) in Amsterdam. No disrespect meant to the Dutch, I applaud their liberal attitude but we aren't ready for it yet. We would like to experience a "family friendly" Amsterdam.

Is that at all possible? I would like to mark it all out on a map. I started doing that but all I have shaded off is the red-light area as suggested by google maps.

Comment: You just gave an idea for my dad's next birthday. Thank you.

Comment: Are cannabis cafes less "family friendly" than regular alcohol cafes?

Comment: Like @HasanKhan I live in Amsterdam, and I never "happen across" the Red Light district. You really only see it if you seek it out. It should be mentioned that it's almost impossible to avoid the sight of sex _shops_, though. So if a shop window full of lingerie and sex toys is a problem, it may be difficult for you to get around. But then, you would have similar trouble in Paris or even Berlin or London.

Comment: @Peter: Since you live there you presumably know where you're going and therefore rarely "happen across" places other than where you're trying to end up. That's probably not representative of the experience of a tourist who _doesn't_ know where he's going but just walks around with no particular aim.

Comment: Your knowledge and evaluation of the situation is of course much more profound, but depending on the age of the "elderly parents", they may have been young adults in the sixties, by which they may even have some more or less indirect acquaintance with the subject matter ...

Comment: @HenningMakholm, fair enough, but if it's the shortest route between two spots, I'd have no trouble walking or cycling through the heart of the red light district. It seems like if you just walk from A to B by the normal routes you very rarely pass through those areas. Of course, I seek out fewer of the tourist hotspots than people who are visiting Amsterdam, but it certainly isn't difficult to consciously avoid.

Comment: @Peter: But that's the point. As a local, when you're moving around in the city you generally have a clear objective of getting from A to B. However, a tourist will as often as not _just be going for a walk_, with no particular As and Bs in mind. (I'm not talking about the difficulty of consciously avoiding something you know where is, but of whether ending up there _by chance_ is possible.)

Comment: @HenningMakholm, true, if you want to make absolutely sure you don't wander across any prostitutes, you should at least check the map. But the fact that you can move around the city for years without ever coming across the area is at least a testament to the fact that it's not _difficult_ to avoid.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen The sixties were not the same everywhere ;-)

Comment: Just admit it: you want to know where the red district and cannabis cafés are, but do not feel like asking it directly. Hence: you ask where they are, and pretend to want to avoid them.

Comment: @QuoraFeans If your comment was directed at me, I find it disrespectful. But then I remember that this is the internet and it is full of people like you. No, if I really wanted to know where the red light district or cannabis cafes were, I wouldn't have to ask here.

Answer (score 10):

The Google Map of the Red Light Disrict is a bit misleading. It highlights the De Wallen district but in reality the majority of the "windows" are in a smaller area inside this district hugging Oudezijds Voorburgwal along the canal and in and around the De Oude Kerk church.

[image]

It can be hard to visit Amsterdam and not see the "sights" of legalised prostitution as there are other smaller areas where it is legal like the one in De Pijp which is along a street of apartments and bars.

However they are easily distinguishable by their neon red lights above windows and doors so they are easily avoidable if necessary. If you do happen to pass one of the windows though you will not see very much. In my experience they were generally empty or the black curtain was drawn.

Regarding the smoking of legalised cannabis these are much harder to avoid as they are present in all areas but confined to coffee shops. But as Relaxed mentioned they are very inconspicuous apart from the odd smell here or there.

There are lots of family friendly activities to do in Amsterdam. The rich architecture, history and art of the city to name a few. Enjoy your trip!

Comment: Thank you. The rich architecture and history is what has us gravitate towards Amsterdam.

Comment: +1 for the map and also for explaining that you generally don't see anything, at least during “visiting“ hours. That has been my experience as well.

Comment: Cannabis is actually not legal in Holland but tolerated

Comment: @greg121 Whether that's the case (or even whether “tolerated” and “legal” are strictly exclusive) is debatable. To me, “tolerance“ is the situation in Germany, where you can't be arrested or sentenced for holding a small, predefined quantity of some substance. When you have places selling the stuff openly, with regulations on their location and mode of operation, it's a bit more than that, even if it's true that the whole system was created through administrative rules rather than statutory changes and it's still illegal to grow or sell large quantities of cannabis.

Comment: Therefore, I don't think david is wrong to call this “legalised cannabis“.

Comment: Being Dutch I can tell you that cannabis is NOT legal, so is it wrong to talk about 'legalized cannabis'. When you are stopped by the police for whatever reason the cannabis you have on you is mostly confiscated and destroyed and can count against you if you have a court case against you.

Comment: @Willeke If that was an answer to my comment, note that being a long-time resident who reads Dutch pretty well and knows the law (even if I am not a citizen), I still disagree and I don't think merely being Dutch makes anyone an authority on the topic…

Comment: @Relaxed There is a distinct difference between Legal/Legalized and 'getolereerd'(officially ignored) and I am not 'just Dutch' I keep an eye on the laws and how they are implied as I do answer on (other) internet sites. I thought that you who are so picky in the use of the right word would appreciate the difference.

Comment: If you visit this area during the night, there will be plenty to see in the windows. Additionally, some pubs in the area allow smoking cannabis inside, though they have big signs stating the fact. But again, this is a night time activity. During the day it will be difficult to find anything untoward unless you go looking for it (or are completely ignorant of what goes on inside a coffee shop). Don't miss out on seeing De Oude Kerk or the Science Centre out of worry!

Answer (score 9):

Places selling cannabis (“coffeshops“) aren't restricted to a particular part of town and can't be avoided entirely (to be accurate, their locations are in fact regulated through a permit system and they are required, e.g., not to be too close from a school, but they are not restricted to one specific neighbourhood). On the other hand, there is not much to see apart from a sign, sometimes a bit of music or a smell for the larger ones. From the outside, many look more like a closed disco or café than anything else. It might not help if you find the very idea disturbing but it's very easy to just move on, or in many cases, not notice them at all.

Avoiding the red light districts (especially the larger one called “De Wallen“) would therefore be the most important. The one in the [Singel area](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singel) in particular is a bit surprising. Whereas you can “feel” you are getting closer to De Wallen (many neon lights, seedy shops, drunken tourists…) and avoid it easily, I once stumbled upon the other one while getting out of a car park. There were a few “windows“ in quiet tree-lined streets in a picturesque neighbourhood, not far from some upscale restaurants and a conference venue, which was a bit disconcerting.

More generally, the Netherlands have become (in)famous for their liberal approach to many things but at the end of the day, all of it is limited in scope, inconspicuous or easy to avoid. Putting things into perspective, the ads or street prostitution I occasionally came across in Germany seemed more obnoxious.

Comment: Being unfamiliar with the several areas in Amsterdam, is there some way you could mark this on a map and screenshot it for your answer? I hope I am not asking for too much! Thank you for your answer.

Comment: Unfortunately, I am not too sure what the exact extent of this. It's somewhere along the canal called the “Singel“, west from the central station. I will see if I can find something.

Comment: @drN [Here is one map](https://www.google.com/maps/d/viewer?ll=52.376287,4.89162&t=h&source=embed&ie=UTF8&msa=0&spn=0.003144,0.006856&z=17&mid=zXx1BV9pYks8.kwy2cZucOXbA). It's apparently smaller now.

Comment: so a "coffeeshop" is different from a "cafe"? "Cafe"=coffee and associated accouterments but "coffee shop"=coffee and associated accouterments and cannabis?

Comment: @drN In Dutch (and some other languages like French or German), “coffeeshop“ is only used for places that sell cannabis. I am not even sure whether they actually serve coffee (they are not allowed to sell alcohol and never looked like a particularly nice place to hang out so I have never tried one). Of course, in English the meaning is broader.

Comment: Cafe sells all drinks from Coffee and tea to strong alcohol, entry is not age restricted but no alcohol is served unless user is 18 or over. Coffeeshop (one word) is a place selling cannabis and associated products and entry is limited to 18 and over.